# Capybara prevents attaching onsubmit event to form

Tags: capybara

In my rails app I attach onsubmit event to my form using jquery like this:

```
$("form.my_form").submit(function(){
   alert("test")
   return true;
 });
```

This is working fine when I manually open the page and submit the form (clicking on the submit button) - I see the alert "test"

BUT I have a Capybara test (over Selenium) that loads the page, fills in some values in the form, and then clicks on submit.
And the function is NOT triggered.

Note 1: when running the test the form is indeed submitted, new values recorded in the DB etc. so there is no problem with clicking on the submit button itself

Note 2: if instead of jquery, in the rails view in the `form_for` tag I put

```
html: {onsubmit: "onsubmitfunc();"}
```

with the alert in the onsubmitfunc() - everything works as expected in the capybara test

Note 3: in order for the jquery way to work the js file is defer loaded e.g.:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', defer: true %>
```

I am very new to JQuery, so am I doing something criminal there?
Or Capybara has some problem? with defer loading of the JS file? Or with JQuery? Any ideas?

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: I am using Selenium. I will read about document ready and post the results

Comment: Although it's not a matter of time, as I put a lot of seconds sleep in my test while researching the problem, so I don't think the problem could be that Capybara runs before the JS is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Selenium - the most common reason would be that you have an error in one of your JS assets.  When in the dev environment all your JS assets are served in separate files which means an error in one file doesn't stop others from being processed.  In the test environment (and production) the assets are concatenated into one file which means an error in any file can cause assets concatenated after it to not be processed.

Check the browsers console log for any JS errors and fix them.

Comment: It seems you were right. Although I didn't have any JS errors in the console, I was missing a lot of semicolons at the end of the lines in the code, which probably was breaking something somewhere. After adding semicolons at the end of each js statement, everything works as expected now. Thx!